# C# CefSharp.OffScreen как его использовать, как получить html с уже выполненным JS

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Здесь есть несколько статей по CefSharp, но как правило примеры кода скудные, и не раскрываю как использовать библиотеку . То что здесь нашёл выкидывает исключения, в общем прошу помочь - привести пример . Как без загрузки фрейма получить html текст с исполненным javascript. Скрипты должны выполнятся все, как в браузере , а не отдельно указанный в Task . 
Привожу пример с отображением в форме для CefSharp.WinForms , мне нужна аналогия кода для CefSharp.OffScreen 57 . DotNet 4.5.2

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    private ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
    private CefSettings settings;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeWebBrowser();
    }
    private void InitializeWebBrowser()
    {
        settings = new CefSettings();

        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "37.75.9.131:8080");
        settings.UserAgent = "Mozila 5.0";

        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(string.Empty) { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

        Controls.Add(browser);
    }
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        browser.Load("https://google.com");
    }
    private async void btnSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var doc = browser.GetMainFrame();
        string text = await doc.GetTextAsync();
    }
}
```

Таким образом я задал Proxy и UserAgent получил исходный код с обработанным JS спарсил текст страницы без разметки.

Html можно получить сл. образом : заменить `string text = await doc.GetTextAsync();` на `string html = await doc.GetSourceAsync();`

Comment: Продемонстрируй неработающий пример, какие исключения он выкидывает.

Comment: Привёл работающий пример выше для WinForms , пытался что-то подобное реализовать для CefSharp.OffScreen при инициализации вылетает исключение в mscorelib .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Пришёл к такому решению для CefSharp.OffScreen**

```
private void btnGetText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         LoadFullText("https://google.com");
    }

    private async void LoadFullText(string url)
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "37.75.9.131:8080");
        settings.UserAgent = "Mozila 5.0";
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        using (var chromium = new ChromiumWebBrowser(string.Empty))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            await LoadPageAsync(chromium, url);
            string text = await chromium.GetTextAsync();
        }
    }

    public static Task LoadPageAsync(IWebBrowser browser, string address = null)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        EventHandler<LoadingStateChangedEventArgs> handler = null;
        handler = (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (!args.IsLoading)
            {
                browser.LoadingStateChanged -= handler;
                tcs.TrySetResultAsync(true);
            }
        };
        browser.LoadingStateChanged += handler;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
        {
            browser.Load(address);
        }
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Для проверки работы просто вставил `Thread.Sleep(1000);` здесь нужно доработать.