# Чем можно заменить WebBrowser C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser

Всем привет. Чем в C# можно заменить WebBrowser? Кроме Awesomium. Он давно уже не обновлялся и некоторые сайты показывает далеко не так, как они должны выглядеть.

В данный момент в одном проекте юзаю Selenium, но это немного не то, что мне надо, т.к. нужно встроить компонент непосредственно в форму.
Знаю, что для WebBrowser с помощью кода, который будет ниже, можно указать какую версию IE можно брать за основу. Только вот это все равно не помогает некоторые сайты отображать правильно. Либо версии IE указаны не самые актуальные, либо что-то еще. Поэтому, если кто-то знает, подскажите и по этому поводу)

```
int BrowserVer, RegVal;

        // get the installed IE version
        using (WebBrowser Wb = new WebBrowser())
            BrowserVer = Wb.Version.Major;

        if (BrowserVer >= 11)
            RegVal = 11001;
        else if (BrowserVer == 10)
            RegVal = 10001;
        else if (BrowserVer == 9)
            RegVal = 9999;
        else if (BrowserVer == 8)
            RegVal = 8888;
        else
            RegVal = 7000;

        // set the actual key
        RegistryKey Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
        Key.SetValue(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe", RegVal, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        Key.Close();
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/825526/Csharp-WebBrowser-vs-Gecko-vs-Awesomium-vs-OpenWeb

Comment: Cef например, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Comment: @yolosora пытался ставить winforms-версию из nugget, в ссылках он так и не появился.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745960/c-cefsharp-offscreen-как-его-использовать-как-получить-html-с-уже-выполненным

Comment: @АндрейФедоров Cef по умолчанию использует сборки x86/x64, для AnyCpu нужны корректировки. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714

Comment: @DigitalCore я выставил x64, скомпилил проект, потом через nuget установил winforms-версию, но ничего все равно не появилось.

Comment: @АндрейФедоров такого быть не может, может вы не ту версию установили, то есть мод какой нить.

Comment: @DigitalCore да нет, ставил самую скачиваемую из списка. Если не сложно, можете собрать проект с уже установленной winforms-версией и скинуть сюда? Мб я действительно что-то не так делаю.

Comment: @АндрейФедоров подключение ссылок `ваш проект\packages\CefSharp.WinForms.63.0.3\CefSharp\x64`

Comment: @АндрейФедоров https://github.com/DigitalCoreLab/CefDemo

Comment: @DigitalCore, перезапустил студию и в моем проекте появились ссылки, спасибо)